# Highchart maps / Highmaps update vue data properties on clicking country

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

The selected country/state name can be accessed in Highchart maps using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MisterSingh/Lk90o3xg/)

But Is there a way to access the vue data properties within event scope?

Basically, If we have a data property in vue as selectedCountry which can be displayed as {{ selectedCountry }}, so is it possible to get and update it using `this.selectedCountry = this.name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it using arrow functions